# Teardown() in Junit testing to reset fields

Tags: java, testing, junit

Trying to do some JUnit testing, but it's been a while so I forget some stuff. If i'm testing a class, i make an object of the class in the @before() but then in the teardown am i not supposed to make it null? that way it erases any problems or anything that could interfere with my next test?

so far i've done this.

```
package potluck.Testing;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import potluck.domain.Controller;
/**
 * @author Samuel
 *
 */
  public class ControllerTest {

  /**
  * @throws java.lang.Exception
  */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    Controller testCntlr = Controller.getInstance();
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
testCntlr() = null;
}


}
```

but it says it can't be resolved to a variable.

Comment: The scope of Controller is in setup(), so how can it be found in tearDown()? Move the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I wasn't instantiating it in the correct place. By declaring it outside the @before, i can just testCntlr.getInstance(); in the @before which makes it new. Then it sees it in the @after.

```
Controller testCntlr;
/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    testCntlr = Controller.getInstance() ;
}

/**
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    testCntlr = null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You do *not* need to set fields to null in the tearDown method.

JUnit runs each test method in a fresh instance of the test class.

Your test will run fine if you just omit the tearDown method.

An `@After` tearDown method is only needed if your tests have side effects beyond the object, such as creating a file or folder, inserting into a database, updating a static field, etc. In those cases, the tearDown method can be used to undo the side effect of the test.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a field on `ControllerTest`. As written, it goes out of scope as soon as `setup()` finishes.

To answer the larger question, though, you probably don't have to do that. Every time you create a new instance in `setup()` you'll throw away the reference to the old one. The old instance shouldn't influence future tests (although there are always ways to make trouble for yourself).